# How to use models from Nuget Package when adding API controller using code generator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, nuget-package, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When adding an API Controller with actions using Entity Framework you select which Model the controller is based on and its DbContext in the following screen:

[image: Add API Controller:]

My models are in a nuget package that I created since other projects need those models too. How to select those models that are in my Nuget Package in the 'Model class' dropdown?

Comment: Suggest editing to add a "visual-studio" tag (perhaps another with "-{versionNumber}"), since this appears to be a question about a Visual Studio feature specifically

Comment: @Luke Done. Starting to think this is not supported yet since the package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design has a TON of bugs in .Net6.0 that aren't getting fixed. I'm just going to ignore the code generator and write it myself. Can't depend on anything from Microsoft.